# Change button size present in WebBrowser dynamically

Tags: javascript, c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a string which contains HTML content.

```
string str = "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type'content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'><style>.containt-box{position:relative; margin-top:-10px;}h3{color:#000000;font-size: 14px;}h5.plainText{color:#000000;font : 14px;}ul.b{liststyletype:square;position: relative;bottom: 0px;}li{font-size : 14px;}.containt-box p{color:#000000;}a:link{color:#ff6600;font-size: 14px;}p{color:#000000;font-size: 14px;}a.button{background-color: #ff6600;border: none;color: white;padding: 10px 15px;text-align:center;textdecoration: none;display: block;font-size: 16px;margin: 0 auto;width: 40%;}</style><script>function setAppFont(fontFamily) { document.body.style.fontFamily = fontFamily; }</script></head><body><a href=\"http://www.google.com" class=\"button\">Learn more</a></body></html>"
```

This string is displayed in webbrowser

> XAML

```
 <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="DescriptionBrowser"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"  Navigating="DescriptionBrowser_Navigating" Margin="0,15,0,0"/>

 <TextBlock x:Name="ErrorBlock" Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
```

> C#

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            ErrorBlock.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            DescriptionBrowser.NavigateToString(str);
            ErrorBlock.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
```

My question is I want to increase the width size of this link present in str in c# code.

```
<a href=\"http://www.google.com" class=\"button\">Learn more</a>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Though your Explanation Looks Confusing .

You Can easily achieve this by setting **Bootstrap** Button class.
If you need to change dinamically yo can use javascript to change current cllass to class mentioned below.

You Create block level buttons—those that span the full width of a parent—by adding **.btn-block** class .

You Create long buttons by adding **.btn-lg** class.